# Dynamically add a variable to an external js script with NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, hotjar

I have this external hotjar script inside `/static/js` of my `nextjs` application.

```
(function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
        h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
        h._hjSettings={hjid:<SITEID>,hjsv:6};
        a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
        r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
        a.appendChild(r);
    })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
```

I have imported this file into my app from inside the `Head` section of `_document.js` like so:
`<script src={'/js/hotjar.js'} ></script>`

**Problem:**
My Nextjs app is currently running on a staging and live environment and I would like to add a script for both. The only dynamic part of the script above is the `SITEID` value here `h._hjSettings={hjid:<SITEID>,hjsv:6};`. How can I add different `SITEID`s for different environments inside a config file and dynamically change this value since this script runs on the client side?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit**:
you can use [react-hotjar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hotjar)  and simply

```
import { hotjar } from 'react-hotjar'; 
hotjar.initialize(hjid, hjsv);// Hotjar ID  and Hotjar Snippet Version
```

Otherwise You have 2 options:

**Option 1**
first make sure your `package.json` start script will set enviroment variable, something like this :

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    ...
  }
```

Then  create 2 hotjar sripts, lets say `/js/prod_hotjar.js` and `/js/staging_hotjar.js` which have appropriate `SITEID` inside.
Then in your `_document.js` detect the current enviroment, and render the appropriate script with something like this :

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
const prod= process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    const url = prod ?  "/js/prod_hotjar.js" : "/js/staging_hotjar.js"
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
        <script src={url} ></script>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

**Option 2**
Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with something like this :

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    const SITEID = prod ?  1234 :  4567 // or any other logic
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `(function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
        h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
        h._hjSettings={hjid:${SITEID},hjsv:6};
        a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
        r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
        a.appendChild(r);
       })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');`}} />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Comment: should we use `next/head` or  Head from  'next/document' ?

Comment: @kartikag01 For `_document.js`, use "next/document". For everything else, use "next/head". Refer: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Comment: I had to initialize `react-hotjar` in the `_document.tsx`