# How to make function component from widget in next.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, widget, next.js

So i want to use following html widget in my next.js app to verify user identities for my service. I have a problem with next.js not using the functions inside the script tag of html when i try to return it from function component. It doesn't even higlight it as a code.

So here is the html widget:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- BLOCKPASS WIDGET SCRIPT -->
    <script src="https://cdn.blockpass.org/widget/scripts/release/3.0.0/blockpass-kyc-connect.prod.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="blockpass-kyc-connect">Connect with Blockpass</button>
    <script>
        const blockpass = new BlockpassKYCConnect(
        'my_client_id', 
        {
            env: 'prod', 
            local_user_id: Date.now() 
        }) 
    
        blockpass.startKYCConnect()

        blockpass.on('KYCConnectSuccess', () => {
            //add code that will trigger when data have been sent. ex:
            //alert('Success!')
        })

        blockpass.on('KYCConnectClose', () => {
            //add code that will trigger when the workflow is finished. ex:
            //alert('Finished!')
        })

        blockpass.on('KYCConnectCancel', () => {
            //add code that will trigger when the workflow is aborted. ex:
            //alert('Cancelled!')
        })
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

And i would like to make react component out of it. i was trying to implement it using the function component, to make it further reusable:

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';


export default function Blockpass () {

  return (
    <Head>
      <!-- BLOCKPASS WIDGET SCRIPT -->
      <script src="https://cdn.blockpass.org/widget/scripts/release/3.0.0/blockpass-kyc-connect.prod.js"></script>
    </Head>
    <body>
      <button id="blockpass-kyc-connect">Connect with Blockpass</button>
      <script>
          const blockpass = new BlockpassKYCConnect(
          'my_client_id', 
          {
              env: 'prod', 
              local_user_id: Date.now() 
          }) 

          blockpass.startKYCConnect()

          blockpass.on('KYCConnectSuccess', () => {
              //add code that will trigger when data have been sent. ex:
              //alert('Success!')
          })

          blockpass.on('KYCConnectClose', () => {
              //add code that will trigger when the workflow is finished. ex:
              //alert('Finished!')
          })

          blockpass.on('KYCConnectCancel', () => {
              //add code that will trigger when the workflow is aborted. ex:
              //alert('Cancelled!')
          })
      </script>   
    </body>
    )
}
```

unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for next.js, as the content of `<script>` tag is not recognized. How can i make this html scripts to work inside my next.js/react/jsx app.

Comment: sure, so i want to add this widget:

Comment: I edited the initial question i hope it's more informative now

Comment: Try using the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop in your `<script>` element. Vaguely related: [Dynamically add a variable to an external js script with NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057718/dynamically-add-a-variable-to-an-external-js-script-with-nextjs).